# Amazon S3 - Server responded with 0 code

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I am trying to upload multiple files (50 files - 9.4 MB size for each file) at a time (using dropzone) on the amazon s3 bucket. After few minutes, getting error "Server responded with 0 code". See below screenshot.[image] My ruby version is 2.2.2, rails 4.2 and carrier wave gem, servers are Nginx and Unicorn.

When I select 50 files (9.4 MB for each file) after few minutes some files are uploaded successfully but some files not uploading and getting this error.

So, what is the reason behind this? what is the solution to fix this issue? Are there any plans which I need to upgrade for upload the big size files S3 bucket? because I need to upload 500 Mb to 1 GB files - 100 files at a time.

Comment: Having the same issue. Have you found a solution?